# While using Tomcat, is it possible to automatically reload client files (js,css,html) without manually refreshing the page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would make minor changes in the client files(css,js,html) during webpage development and files were on tomcat server , but I have to reload the whole web page to see the changes, While using Tomcat, is it possible to automatically reload client files (js,css,html) without manually refreshing the page in Google Chrome and just from source tab for developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by hosting your web page on a live server
If you are coding on VS code you can install an extension called Live server in which once you save your file the browser will immediately reload the page refreshing it.
If you are using any other code editors I suggest you look into similar live server extensions.